# Index php array by array variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have a little problem. I need index an php array by array variable.

Example:

```
$structure = [];
$url = "/one/two/three";
$urlParts = explode("/", $url);

// I need convert $urlParts -> to array index ["one"]["two"]["three"]
// Expected result
$structure["one"]["two"]["three"] = true;
```

Is it possible in php language?

Comment: You want to do that with `.htaccess` or with PHP itself?

Comment: Variable $url is just for example. I need it for similar use-case in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use reference to get it like this:

```
<?php
$urlParts = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
$o = [];
$ref = &$o;
$len = count($urlParts);
foreach($urlParts as $k => $v)
{
    $ref[$v] = [];
    $ref = &$ref[$v];
}
$ref = true;
var_dump($o);
echo var_dump($o['one']['two']['three']);
```

output:

```
ei@localhost:~$ php test.php
array(1) {
  ["one"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["two"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["three"]=>
      &bool(true)
    }
  }
}
bool(true)
```